# How to get a Brackets module to work properly?

Tags: javascript, adobe-brackets

I forked Brackets, because I'm planning to make a code editor fully integrated if Steam. To do so, using Javascript, I add a git submodule on the [thirdparty](https://github.com/GeekEngine/geekengine/tree/master/src/thirdparty) folder to use the [greenworks](https://github.com/greenheartgames/greenworks) repo (a solution to make Steamworks work with Javascript). I loaded this module on **brackets.js**, like so:

```
// Load greenworks module
var greenworks          = require("thirdparty/greenworks/greenworks");
```

But when I call it, either on my extension, or even on console, it says:

```
[Extension] failed to load C:/Program Files (x86)/Brackets/dev/src/extensions/dev/greenworks - Error: Module name "/thirdparty/greenworks/greenworks" has not been loaded yet for context: _
```

or

```
 Error: Module name "/thirdparty/greenworks/greenworks" has not been loaded yet for context: _
```

Besides **brackets.js**, where else should I call greenworks module before I use it (on a extension, or on the console for testing purposes)?